# Giving only a specific application access to a network share

Tags: security, networking, windows-7, auditing

My company has a situation where we have a special release of an internal desktop server app for one of our clients to run. The application needs access to a specific network share which for auditing/security purposes we can't let the client directly access outside of what our application does. Does anyone have a suggested solution or approach for this?

Btw, our client machine and the machines we internally run the app on are using Windows 7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suppose this were possible. Since the application is running as the client, the client has full control over it, so the client can patch the program so it accesses the server any way the client likes. In other words, you have gained nothing in terms of security. (Windows security is based on principals, and applications are not principals.)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Windows service running as a specific user; grant access to the network share only to that specific user. Change the main application to communicate with that Windows service for accessing the share.

This assumes that your company controls the computer where the main application is installed; if that's not the case, change the Windows service to a web service.